# Error en la impresión de un objeto de una clase en Python

Tags: python, poo

Dado el siguiente código:

```
    class Menu:
        def __init__(self, comidas, precios):
            self.comida = comidas
            self.precios = precios

        def __str__(self):
            for i in range(len(comidas)):
                print(f'{self.comida[i]}: {self.precios[i]}')

    comidas = ['Pato a la mostaza', 'Hamburguesa', 'Ensalada', 'Lasagna']
    precios = [20000, 8000, 6000, 9000]
    menu = Menu(comidas, precios)
    print(menu)
```

El resultado pedido por la plataforma debería ser:

Pato a la mostaza: 20000

Hamburguesa: 8000

Ensalada: 6000

Lasagna: 9000

Si ejecutamos este programa devuelve lo 'pedido' ademas de eso me da un error en la parte:

print(menu)

A que se debe este error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No debes imprimir nada en el método `__str__`, dicho método **debe retornar una cadena (`str`)** que represente el objeto, generalmente de una forma "amena para humanos".

El error es bastante explicativo al respecto:

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

es decir, se espera que `__str__` retorne un objeto `str` pero esta retornando `None` (retorno por defecto de toda función/método en Python).

`__str__`  es llamado por `str()`, `format()` y `print()` cuando se aplican sobre el objeto y su retorno es usado para realizar la tarea que cada una hace, en el caso de `print` imprime la cadena retornada en la salida estándar.

Por ejemplo, usando `str.join` para unir las cadenas generadas en el `for` puedes hacer:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "\n".join(f'{self.comida[i]}: {self.precios[i]}' for i in range(len(self.comida)))
```

Básicamente es similar a:

```
def __str__(self):
    cadena = ""
    for i in range(len(self.comida)):
        cadena += f'{self.comida[i]}: {self.precios[i]}\n'
    return cadena
```

aunque esto es considerablemente mas ineficiente.

Otra opción usando `zip`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "\n".join(f'{comida}: {precio}' for comida, precio in zip(self.comida, self.precios))
```